# Excel file (Microsoft excel macro-enabled worksheet) cannot be opened inside GDrive (and file stream)

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-drive-file-stream

After transferring my files from the desktop to Google Drive, I tried to open the file with Excel in Google Drive with file stream, but an error keeps showing up and stops me from opening it.

However, the file can be downloaded and I can open it after download. But it will be too troublesome as I have to transfer it back to the Google Drive after I have edited the file.

Hence, is there any way such that I can open the Excel file directly from Google Drive and edit/save in there?

Below attached is the error that was shown when I opened the file in Google Drive.

[image: error shown]

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out that the same issue was that the file name (read: path) was too long. I just have to shorten the file/folder name and it could be opened!